# Ц(?)гейка и цыгане

Tags: этимология, орфография

Добрый вечер!

Связаны ли слова *ц(?)гейк*а и *цыган*? В качестве правильного варианта в словарях встречала только написание через *и*, но это слово точно не производное от народа? Ведь цыгане как кочевое племя действительно занимались скотоводством, одевались в овечий мех.

---

Нашла версию, что *ц(и)гейка* могла произойти от немецкой *козы*. Честно говоря, это не кажется очень убедительным. В смысле: сначала делали "цигейки" из козьего меха, а потом стали делать из овечьего? А название оставили тем же? Есть ли подобные примеры?

Более вероятным мне кажется вторая гипотеза: происхождение "цигейки" от "цигайской" породы овец. Если почитать про них, то оказывается, что это одна из древнейших пород Малой Азии. Цыгане, живущие за счёт своих животных (в большей степени, чем за счёт конокрадства, тут достаточно сравнить масштабы), с очень большой вероятностью могли разводить в том числе и этих животных.

Может ошибаюсь, но почему-то кажется, что в классической литературе (почему-то на ум приходит проза Горького) часто встречала в "мужицкой речи" слова, в которых некоторые согласные были заменены на *й*. Могла ли такая подмена произойти и в "цыганской" породе? Информацию о происхождении этого названия (как и самих овец) найти не удалось.

---

Соответственно, вопрос такой: если *ц(?)гайская* порода связана с цыганами, то как производное слово она должна писаться через "ы", в таком случае так же следует писать и *ц(?)гейку*. Возможно ли это? Откуда что пошло?

Спасибо.

Comment: Не смущает ударная несовпадающая гласная? Почему цыгане — не цыгеи?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А почему Вы связываете правописание и этимологию именно этих слов?

Написание И/Ы связано с древней фонетикой. Изначально звук ц у наших предков был мягким и глухим. Отвердение Ц в нецокающих говорах, по написаниям в памятниках ЦЪ, ЦЫ, относится к XVI веку: Домострой, конец XVI века –КОНЕЦЪ, КОНЦЫ.

Сложилось такое правило - после ц пишется ы в русских и обрусевших словах: концы, молодцы, лисицын (в окончании и суффиксе, потому что в корне Ц не встречалось) , а также в словах исключениях - цыган, цыпленок, на цыпочках, цыпка, цыкнуть, цыц и производных от них.

В иноязычных словах сохраняется написание и после ц: цинк, цирк, лекция, циновка.

До реформы 1956 г. слов с ы после ц в корне слова было больше - цынга, цыновка, панцырь, цыфирь, цырюльник и нек. др. Почему отменили Ы именно в этих словах, но оставили в ныне действующих словах-исключениях? Так решили авторы реформы. Видимо, потому что иностранные, хотя давно освоены русским языком.

Слова цыпленок, цыпочки, цыкать, цыц имеют специфические междометные корни, что оправдывает их особое(русское) написание.

Что касается существительного цыган, то это слово осталось единственным в списке исключений, не имеющим междометного корня. Вероятно, это связано с тем, что цыган – слово с богатой культурно-исторической традицией (например, оно употребляется в названии поэмы А. С. Пушкина) и лингвисты понимали, что изменение его написания многими было бы воспринято болезненно.Хотя и заимствованное.

Так что цигейка и цыган никак не связаны, только похожестью произнесения.

Comment: Спасибо. Про реформу интересно.

Answer (score 1):

Слова *цигейка* и *цыган* этимологически не связаны.

Ц**и**гейка — стриженый и крашеный мех овцы (первоначально козы). Это слово восходит к немецкому *Ziege* "коза" (происхождение которого, в общем, [неясно](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Ziege)). *("Толковый словарь русского языка с включением сведений о происхождении слов" РАН)*

Цыгане — народность индийского происхождения, живущая обычно кочевыми и полукочевыми группами в разных странах мира. Этноним *цыган* был заимствован из румынского *Cigǎn*, восходящего к прототипу геродотовского этнонима со значением
"кочевая народность, переселившаяся из Мидии в долину Истра (Дуная)". *(Этимологический словарь современного русского языка"  А. К. Шапошникова)*

Написание *ц**ы**ган* считается исключением (др.-рус. *ц**ы**ганъ*).

> В смысле: сначала делали "цигейки" из козьего меха, а потом стали делать из овечьего? А название оставили тем же? Есть ли подобные примеры?

Чем-то напоминает этимологию слова *слон*: считается, что оно исторически связано с турецким *aslan* "лев" (то есть названия одного животного в языке-источнике стало обозначать другого в заимствующем языке).